# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist while using default Generation Strategy in Hibernate with Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to save below entity in Oracle database.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}



Book book1 = new Book();
book1.setName("Sample");
session.save(book1);
```

But Hibernate is generating below exception stack trace.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
```

Also I am seeing Hibernate is trying to run below query to fetch value from sequence, which is when the exception is getting generated.

`Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual`

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK(
    ID INTEGER,
    NAME VARCHAR2(50)
);

ALTER TABLE BOOK ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);
```

Comment: Does the sequence exist? Which user are you using to run your query? Is it the same than the sequence? If not, have you created synonyms, given grants, ... ?

Comment: Can you add `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to your `id` member variable and try? Also, you should declare member variables in Entity class like `private Integer id;` rather `private int id;`.

Comment: @harshavmb, still not working with the changes u suggested.

Comment: Can you tell us to which table `Book` is mapped to ? Also, if you could post the table schema it would be helpful

Comment: The problem is clear, you aren't setting `id` so hibernate is complaining.

Comment: Which `generator` type you used in mapping file? By any chance you used `native` ?

Comment: @harshavmb I tried this code on another machine having Oracle DB only, and it is working fine. Could this be a db specific issue? Also I am not using any mapping file.

Comment: Nope, am not seeing `auto_increment` on `BOOK` table. Can you alter `book` table with this query `CREATE SEQUENCE book_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;`?. If there are any existing rows, it may complain. Then truncate the table, run the above query and re-insert the data. Also, can you share the hibernate mapping file, I would like to have a look on it

Comment: Without mapping file, how hibernate would know which entity has to be mapped to database table.

Comment: @harshavmb I have added `new Configuration().addAnnotatedClass(Book.class)` code in my DAO class. So I don't need mapping xml file. Also the same code is working on another system with table schema. Could this be a database level issue?

Comment: I don't see `@Table` annotation on you `Book` entity class pointing to `book` table and you are saying there is no mapping file. I'm not sure how hibernate works in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run this program on another machine which I had been using for Hibernate programs for quite a few time. But the program failed to run on a new machine and the reason is apparent in the stack trace :

```
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual.
```

Hibernate is not able to find out the default `hibernate_sequence` in database. So instead of creating the sequence manually I added the property

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

in `hibernate.cfg.xml` and the next time I ran the program, Hibernate created this sequence and added a new row in `Book` table.

Comment: Note: As @Sergio mentioned, Adding this line: <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> to your Hibernate configuration will drop all your tables and recreate them empty. Please use this carefully

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line:
`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`
to your Hibernate configuration will drop all your tables and recreate them empty.